# How can I further improve the speed a TinyYolo Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I want to detect human hands on a Raspberry Pi 4 (2GB, overclocked to 1950Mhz)

I found this [project](https://github.com/Qengineering/TensorFlow_Lite_SSD_RPi_64-bits) which claims to run object detection with 24 fps. I was able to get 10 fps while loading the model in python rather that using c++ and tencents ncnn framework.

While this is a satisfying framerate for my project, it doesn't really help me, because its used to detect everyday objects rather than human hands.

After talking to the author of the project, Tiny Yolo was recommended for my application, and that's what I have tried so far:

**Python imports**

```
import time
import torch
import torchvision
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from IPython.display import display
from torch.jit._trace import trace_module
```

**Image loading and processing**

```
def load_image(idx, size, device="cpu"):
    #filename = f"VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/2008_{str(idx).zfill(6)}.jpg"
    filename = 'bus.jpg'
    img = Image.open(filename)
    transforms = [torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()]
    try:
        width, height = size
    except TypeError:
        width = height = size
    scale = min(width / img.width, height / img.height)
    new_width, new_height = int(img.width * scale), int(img.height * scale)
    diff_width, diff_height = width - new_width, height - new_height
    resize = torchvision.transforms.Resize(size=(new_height, new_width))
    pad = torchvision.transforms.Pad(
        padding=(
            diff_width // 2,
            diff_height // 2,
            diff_width // 2 + diff_width % 2,
            diff_height // 2 + diff_height % 2,
        )
    )
    transforms = [resize, pad] + transforms
    transformation = torchvision.transforms.Compose(transforms)
    x = transformation(img).to(device)
    return x

def load_image_batch(idxs, size, device="cpu"):
    imgs = [load_image(idx, size=size, device="cpu") for idx in idxs]
    x = torch.stack(imgs, 0)
    return x.to(device)

def show_images(x):
    transform = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()
    if x.dim() == 3:
        display(transform(x))
    elif x.dim() == 4:
        for xx in x:
            display(transform(xx))
    else:
        raise ValueError

def show_images_with_boxes(input_tensor, output_tensor):
    to_img = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()
    for img, predictions in zip(input_tensor, output_tensor):
        img = to_img(img)
        if 0 in predictions.shape: # empty tensor
            display(img)
            continue
        confidences = predictions[..., 4].flatten()
        boxes = (
            predictions[..., :4].contiguous().view(-1, 4)
        )  # only take first four features: x0, y0, w, h
        classes = predictions[..., 5:].contiguous().view(boxes.shape[0], -1)
        boxes[:, ::2] *= img.width
        boxes[:, 1::2] *= img.height
        boxes = (torch.stack([
                    boxes[:, 0] - boxes[:, 2] / 2,
                    boxes[:, 1] - boxes[:, 3] / 2,
                    boxes[:, 0] + boxes[:, 2] / 2,
                    boxes[:, 1] + boxes[:, 3] / 2,
        ], -1, ).cpu().to(torch.int32).numpy())
        for box, confidence, class_ in zip(boxes, confidences, classes):
            if confidence < 0.01:
                continue # don't show boxes with very low confidence
            # make sure the box fits within the picture:
            box = [
                max(0, int(box[0])),
                max(0, int(box[1])),
                min(img.width - 1, int(box[2])),
                min(img.height - 1, int(box[3])),
            ]
            try:  # either the class is given as the sixth feature
                idx = int(class_.item())
            except ValueError:  # or the 20 softmax probabilities are given as features 6-25
                idx = int(torch.max(class_, 0)[1].item())
            try:
                class_ = CLASSES[idx]  # the first index of torch.max is the argmax.
            except IndexError: # if the class index does not exist, don't draw anything:
                continue

            
            color = (  # green color when confident, red color when not confident.
                int((1 - (confidence.item())**0.8 ) * 255),
                int((confidence.item())**0.8 * 255),
                0,
            )
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
            draw.rectangle(box, outline=color)
            draw.text(box[:2], class_, fill=color)
            
        display(img)
```

I've found a **Tiny Yolo v2** implementation which I adjusted slightly and added a width-multiplier:

```
CLASSES = ('hand')

class TinyYOLOv2(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes=1,
        anchors=(
            (1.08, 1.19),
            (3.42, 4.41),
            (6.63, 11.38),
            (9.42, 5.11),
            (16.62, 10.52),
        ),
    ):
        super().__init__()

        width_mult = 0.6

        # Parameters
        self.register_buffer("anchors", torch.tensor(anchors))
        self.num_classes = num_classes

        # Layers
        self.relu = torch.nn.LeakyReLU(0.1, inplace=True)
        self.pool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.slowpool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, 1)
        self.pad = torch.nn.ReflectionPad2d((0, 1, 0, 1))
        self.norm1 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(16, momentum=0.1)
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm2 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(32 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(16, int(32 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm3 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(64 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(32 * width_mult), int(64 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm4 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(128 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(64 * width_mult), int(128 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm5 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(256 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(128 * width_mult), int(256 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm6 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(512 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv6 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(256 * width_mult), int(512 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm7 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(1024 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv7 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(512 * width_mult), int(1024 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.norm8 = torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(int(1024 * width_mult), momentum=0.1)
        self.conv8 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(1024 * width_mult), int(1024 * width_mult), 3, 1, 1, bias=False)
        self.conv9 = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(1024 * width_mult), len(anchors) * (5 + num_classes), 1, 1, 0)

    def forward(self, x, yolo=True):
        x = self.relu(self.pool(self.norm1(self.conv1(x))))
        x = self.relu(self.pool(self.norm2(self.conv2(x))))
        x = self.relu(self.pool(self.norm3(self.conv3(x))))
        x = self.relu(self.pool(self.norm4(self.conv4(x))))
        x = self.relu(self.pool(self.norm5(self.conv5(x))))
        x = self.relu(self.slowpool(self.pad(self.norm6(self.conv6(x)))))
        x = self.relu(self.norm7(self.conv7(x)))
        x = self.relu(self.norm8(self.conv8(x)))
        x = self.conv9(x)
        if yolo:
            x = self.yolo(x)
        return x
    
    def yolo(self, x):
        # store the original shape of x
        nB, _, nH, nW = x.shape

        # reshape the x-tensor: (batch size, # anchors, height, width, 5+num_classes)
        x = x.view(nB, self.anchors.shape[0], -1, nH, nW).permute(0, 1, 3, 4, 2)

        # get normalized auxiliary tensors
        anchors = self.anchors.to(dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
        range_y, range_x = torch.meshgrid(
            torch.arange(nH, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device),
            torch.arange(nW, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device),
        )
        anchor_x, anchor_y = anchors[:, 0], anchors[:, 1]
        
        # compute boxes.
        x = torch.cat([
            (x[:, :, :, :, 0:1].sigmoid() + range_x[None,None,:,:,None]) / nW,  # X center
            (x[:, :, :, :, 1:2].sigmoid() + range_y[None,None,:,:,None]) / nH,  # Y center
            (x[:, :, :, :, 2:3].exp() * anchor_x[None,:,None,None,None]) / nW,  # Width
            (x[:, :, :, :, 3:4].exp() * anchor_y[None,:,None,None,None]) / nH,  # Height
            x[:, :, :, :, 4:5].sigmoid(), # confidence
            x[:, :, :, :, 5:].softmax(-1), # classes
        ], -1)

        return x # (batch_size, # anchors, height, width, 5+num_classes)

# For tracing and speed-test
input_tensor = load_image_batch([0], 320)

# Create Models
model = TinyYOLOv2()
quantized = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(model, {torch.nn.Conv2d, torch.nn.BatchNorm2d}, dtype=torch.qint8)
traced = torch.jit.trace(model, input_tensor)
quantized_traced = torch.jit.trace(quantized, input_tensor)

While Tiny Yolo already should be somehow optimized for low-perfomance 
deviced, the model still only runs with max 3.5 fps on the Raspberry Pi on which I want to deploy it in the end.

Using the `trace`-function, which according to some tutorials brought an 100% speed-increase helped a little bit on pi (while weirdly slowing the model down on the macbook) and quantization wasnt helpful at all:

# Test

pTime = time.time()
output_tensor = model(input_tensor)
cTime = time.time()
print('OG FPS: ', 1.0 / (cTime - pTime)) # -> 83.43 MacBook Air M2 // 2.47 RPi 4 GB 1950 MHz

pTime = time.time()
output_tensor = traced(input_tensor)
cTime = time.time()
print('Traces FPS: ', 1.0 / (cTime - pTime)) # -> 47.32 MBA M2 // 3.53 RPi 

pTime = time.time()
output_tensor = quantized(input_tensor)
cTime = time.time()
print('Quantized FPS: ', 1.0 / (cTime - pTime)) # -> 83.91 MBA M2 // 1.72 RPi

pTime = time.time()
output_tensor = quantized_traced(input_tensor)
cTime = time.time()
print('Quantized + Traced FPS: ', 1.0 / (cTime - pTime)) # -> 54.31 // 1.98 RPi
```

Even with a width-multiplier of only 0.3, the Pi peaks with 5 fps.

How can I further optimise the model to get into the range of about 10 fps?
Is this approach even somehow promising?
It is important to know that these tests were run before the model was trained as I made these to get a rough understanding of the speed before I waste to much time with training.

As I understand it, the speed can change with different weights, but it should be okay as an estimation.

I know about the underlying math like backpropagation, but with complex models like yolo there could be several things I misunderstood.

Kind regards and thanks in advance,
Jan

Edit: Reducing the number layers is obviously also an option, but this is all very complex I would appreciate a recommendation on how what options are the most promising

Edit: My specific problem is, that the model is too "slow", what else should I specify? I gave an example for a model which runs faster than mine and I would like to know how that can be achieved.

I know that the given model uses a different architecture, but yolo seems to be the modern approach and should be able to give similar results

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.